# ReSharper Code Inspection not working

Tags: c#, resharper, code-inspection

When I open a Code Behind file with F7 in Visual Studio (it's a Form), ReSharper's Code Inspection is not working. To get any information about errors I have to reenable the VS C# coding errors.
Are Code Behind files excluded from analysis?

Thx
Tim

Comment: Nope they're not. Sounds like a bug to me. Which Version of ReSharper & VisualStudio are you using?

Comment: VS 2013 and ReSharper 2016.3.2

Comment: Since when does this problem exist? When did it first happen and what did you do before? Did you already restart VS, or is this a very temporar problem? If you manage to reproduce it independently, report it to Resharper.

Comment: The problem is permanent. It is right from start up. I think @MetaColon is right and I will report this to JetBrains. THX

Comment: Strange though - it seems to work for me. Could you provide a clarification of what exactly isn't working? Is the option just missing, isn't it showing results or is it showing wrong results?

Comment: Actually no code hints are show, no errors also the red, green, yellow indicator at the top of the scroll bar is missing.

Comment: Trey reinstalling it, or install a higher version of VS/Resharper

Comment: Jetrains had introduced a threshold, based on the amount of lines. With Ctrl+Alt+Shift+8 R# is forced to run code inspections in those files. More information can be found here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462298